# Azure Event Hubs C Client

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-eventhub

I am trying to send messages to Azure Event Hubs from an Arduino with a Wifi extension. Is there a way to upload the data without using the provided libraries?

Comment: Use the REST API - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn790674.aspx

Comment: Remember that Event Hubs (Service Bus in general) needs SSL connection. If you are using Arduino Uno, you don't have this possibility

Answer (score 0):

You will need some kind of device to act as a gateway. The Adruino board cannot provide this functionality. Most likely, you will need to connect the device to a Raspberry Pi and send the messages using the Pi. Below is directions and code on how to set this up.
https://github.com/MSOpenTech/connectthedots